# How does deleteAllBy... method work in Spring Data JPA? Why does it it make more DELETE queries then needed?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

In my project I was using this method for my entity repository

```
void deleteAllByCompanyBranch_Id(Long companyBranchId);
```

And the result was a little bit weird, Hibernate generated DELETE query for each entity, instead of doing it only once and I can't understand why. Here is Hibernate's log

```
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        department 
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        department 
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        department 
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        department 
    where
        id=?
```

As you can see Hibernate generates four delete queries for each row related to company branch.

If I am using a custom query like this

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "DELETE Department d WHERE d.companyBranch.id = :companyBranchId")
void deleteAllByCompanyBranch_Id(Long companyBranchId);
```

Hibernate generates only one query

```
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        department 
    where
        company_branch_id=?
```

Why can't hibernate do the same for `deleteAllBy...` method from Spring Data JPA? What's the point of this query method if it can not delete all entities with one query? When should I use it and when should I not?

Comment: Probably because delete all expects an Iterable. Why not call it `deleteBy...`?

Comment: The delete query is generated by Spring Data **not** hibernate. Next to that what might seem logical to you, might not be to hibernate as that only has the metadata it can operate on.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz because i want to delete all entities with one go, will `deleteBy...` handle this?

Comment: @M.Deinum oh, i didnt know about this, but still whats the difference between my custom query and `deleteAllBy...` method? How does it work?

Comment: You would need to look at the query builder in Spring Data to determine what that is doing. I would suspect that there is even a `SELECT` before the `DELETE` instances. Why, because else Hibernate won't know what to delete as it would need the entity mapping to determine if nested relationships need to be deleted as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum just checked it out, yeah, there is really a `SELECT` query before deleting entity, now i understand why, but I also noticed that if i am using custom query for deleting department entities, there is no such query, so is it better to use custom queries for updating / deleting entities? Or maybe there is not such query because I am executing this query first: `@Query(value = "DELETE FROM Employee e WHERE e.department.id IN (SELECT d.id from Department d where d.companyBranch.id = :companyBranchId)")` ?

Comment: If you provide a query that will be executed as is, it will not use the JPA metamodel then to traverse relations etc. etc.